# how to remove index.php from codeigniter url using window rdp (tried many solutions)

Tags: codeigniter

I know this question has been asked many times but have tried all the solutions but invain

My Config file is as follow

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://immodernafrican.com';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

.htaccess file is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|static|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|uploads|googlexxxxxxxx\.html|mobile.html)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Changed

```
AllowOverride None
```

To

```
AllowOverride All
```

but still my url works with index.php

```
immodernafrican.com/index.php/AncientHistory
```

other than that it gives 404 error

```
immodernafrican.com/AncientHistory
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Change your `.htaccess` to this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|image|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your .htaccess file will be

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
        RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]



</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Config file

```
$config['base_url'] = '';

$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Comment: tried your config and htaccess but still website not working without index.php

Answer (score 0):

Follow this

**For Server**

1. Activate mode_rewrite module

   ```
   sudo a2enmod rewrite
   ```
2. Restart the apache

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```
3. edit 000-default.conf

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
   ```
4. Search for “DocumentRoot /var/www/html” and add the following lines directly below:

   ```
   <Directory "/var/www/html">
       AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
   ```
5. Save and exit the nano editor via CTRL-X, “y” and ENTER.
6. Restart the server:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

in config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://immodernafrican.com';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

in routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "YOUR_DEFAULT_CONTROLLER";
```

htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]    

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Added more steps for solving problems. I myself host projects using this settings