# amazon aws error :- This page isn’t working ec2-34-201-168-76.compute-1.amazonaws.com is currently unable to handle this request

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

from the last two days.I tried everything to run my codeigniter project from aws ec2 ubuntu instance.I uploaded all the files on the aws ec2 instance.Given all the permissions.

Whenever I try yo load my page it gives this error :- *This page isn’t working ec2-34-201-168-76.compute-1.amazonaws.com is currently unable to handle this request.*

My htaccess is as given below :-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]

    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.trailermantra\.com [NC]
    #RewriteRule (.*) http://www.trailermantra.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

you can check my phpinfo from the link :-[php info link](http://ec2-34-201-168-76.compute-1.amazonaws.com/test.php)`
project folder :- [project folder](http://ec2-34-201-168-76.compute-1.amazonaws.com/g2g)

my error.log file of apache :-`[Sat May 20 18:48:54.774017 2017] [:error] [pid 8335] [client 103.245.15.74:7509] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function result() on a non-object in /var/www/html/g2g/application/config/routes.php on line 119
[Sat May 20 18:48:57.327290 2017] [:error] [pid 8336] [client 103.245.15.74:7508] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function result() on a non-object in /var/www/html/g2g/application/config/routes.php on line 119
[Sat May 20 19:19:08.549065 2017] [:error] [pid 8337] [client 103.245.15.74:5255] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function result() on a non-object in /var/www/html/g2g/application/config/routes.php on line 119
[Sat May 20 19:19:10.397866 2017] [:error] [pid 8333] [client 103.245.15.74:5256] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function result() on a non-object in /var/www/html/g2g/application/config/routes.php on line 119
[Sat May 20 19:26:02.574040 2017] [:error] [pid 8334] [client 103.245.15.74:5342] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function result() on a non-object in /var/www/html/g2g/application/config/routes.php on line 119
[Sat May 20 19:28:58.594397 2017] [:error] [pid 8333] [client 103.245.15.74:5389] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function result() on a non-object in /var/www/html/g2g/application/config/routes.php on line 119
[Sat May 20 19:53:20.482458 2017] [:error] [pid 8334] [client 103.245.15.74:7428] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function result() on a non-object in /var/www/html/g2g/application/config/routes.php on line 119`

Comment: Show your config parameters and try to put simple `index.html` under `g2g` folder and see its accessible or not. What's written under `routes.php` on line 119?

Comment: i can access my index.html in g2g folder.

Comment: replace your `RewriteRule` with `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /g2g/index.php?/$1 [L]`

Comment: So what is in `routes.php` on line 119?

Comment: try this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41727166/3898339), I use to deploy codeigniter project like this on ec2 ubuntu